# Autofill in VBA only working in debugger?

Tags: excel, vba

First time I have messaged on here and pretty new to VBA too, so apologies if my code is awful.
When I run through the code below in the debugger it works perfectly and does exactly what I'm expecting.

However, when I run it via the button I created the autofill part doesn't work.
Whilst the header (pricing_id) appears and so does the number from cell I14.
I might be missing something simple, I'm not sure.

For clarity on the below code, I added the copy and paste special values in the hope it would keep the autofill however it didn't.

```
Sub CopyPricingID()

    Sheets("Insert Booking file").Range("AC1").Value = "pricing_ID"
    Sheets("Insert Booking file").Range("AC2").Value = _
    Sheets("Booking File").Range("I14").Value

    lr = Worksheets("Insert Booking file").Range("A1:AC1000").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

    Range("AC2").AutoFill Range("AC2:AC" & lr)
    Sheets("Insert Booking file").Cells.Copy
    Sheets("Insert Booking file").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox "Complete"


End Sub
```

I hope I have explained this ok and any help on this will be brilliant and much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Range("AC2").AutoFill Range("AC2:AC" & lr)` with

```
Dim src As Range
Dim dest As Range
Set src = Worksheets("Insert Booking file").Range("AC2")
Set dest = Worksheets("Insert Booking file").Range("AC2:AC" & lr)
src.AutoFill Destination:=dest
'Range("AC2").AutoFill Range("AC2:AC" & lr)
```

This makes  sure you always work with the right sheet. Your line refers to the `ActiveSheet`which might not always be the sheet you want.

Comment: Hi Storax, that worked for me perfectly ,thank you so much! And the explanation helps alot too. Will keep that in mind moving forward.